# My Menu Bar hiding under javascript of PasteBin

Tags: javascript, css, overlapping

Please Help me to build my Menu Bar Correctly.
I am making a Navigation Panel (Spry MenuBar) in Adobe Dreamweaver. The provided code by dreamweaver is running well on my website, but when the submenu opens downwards then it hides under the JavaScript of PasteBin & I am not able to see the Sub Menu Items...

My MenuBar's CSS Code is on - [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/d3PEn2E9)

My MenuBar's JAVAScript Code is on - [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/kP4pciSU)

Comment: What does this have to do with `java`? Please remove the tag. I also doubt it has anything to do with `jsp`

Comment: You might want to consider posting your *MenuBar* HTML code for testing.

Comment: You should also consider extracting only the code needed to answer the question and posting it with the question(the parts dealing w/ the issue), or providing a link to that section.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly that should be something to do with your CSS.
Set the z-index css property of your sub-menu, to a higher value.
That should do.
If that doesn't fix it, paste the menu's html, css and javascript in http://jsfiddle.net/